# JSON Data Deserialize in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I am trying to Deserialize Json format data code which I have written

```
 string strJSONData = "[{ \"StatusValue\": \"Test1\", \"StatusValue1\": \"Test2\", \"StatusValue2\": \"Test3\", \"StatusValue3\": \"Test4\", \"test\": \"hibaby\"  }, { \"StatusValue\": \"aTest1\", \"StatusValue1\": \"bTest2\", \"StatusValue2\": \"cTest3\", \"StatusValue3\": \"dTest4\",\"test\": \"hibaby u\" }]";

        JavaScriptSerializer objJavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<StatusValueTest> objStatus = objJavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<StatusValueTest>>(strJSONData);

        foreach (StatusValueTest val in objStatus)
        {
            Label1.Text += val.StatusValue;
        }
    }
```

And two class:

```
public class StatusValueTest
{

public string StatusValue { get; set; }

public string StatusValue1 { get; set; }

public string StatusValue2 { get; set; }

public string StatusValue3 { get; set; }

public List<StatusList> ram { get; set; }

public StatusValueTest()
{
    ram = new List<StatusList>();
}

}
```

and

```
public class StatusList
{
    public string test { get; set; }

    public StatusList()
    {

    }
}
```

jSON data : `"[{ \"StatusValue\": \"Test1\", \"StatusValue1\": \"Test2\", \"StatusValue2\": \"Test3\", \"StatusValue3\": \"Test4\", \"test\": \"hibaby\"  },
 { \"StatusValue\": \"aTest1\", \"StatusValue1\": \"bTest2\", \"StatusValue2\": \"cTest3\", \"StatusValue3\": \"dTest4\",\"test\": \"hibaby u\" }]";`

In StatusValue, StatusValue1, StatusValue2, StatusValue3 is coming but value is not coming in **test**.I am not able to figure out why this happening ..Please help me out here

Comment: here is a Stackoverflow posting that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244149/parse-json-string-using-json-net

Comment: Is this JSON being recieved

Comment: @ElRonnoco no actually it is hard coded value

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to modify your JSON data? It should look more like this:

```
[{ \"StatusValue\": \"Test1\", 
\"StatusValue1\": \"Test2\", 
\"StatusValue2\": \"Test3\", 
\"StatusValue3\": \"Test4\", 
\"ram\": {\"test"\", hibaby\"} 
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got everything right your json look probably should like the following

```
[{ 
"StatusValue": "Test1", 
"StatusValue1": "Test2", 
"StatusValue2": "Test3", 
"StatusValue3": "Test4", 
"ram ": 
[{
"test":"hibaby" 
},{
"test":"hibaby1" 
}]
}]
```