# Json.Net Parse json of different format

Tags: c#, javascript, json, node.js

1. A Chat Room sample program created with NodeJs.
2. Node.js server will response 3 different format of Json.
3. I have created a Winform program to accept Json from Websocket.
4. I use Json.NET JsonMessage jsonResponse = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Message.ToString());
   to deSerialize one format of Node.js
5. How to identify different format of Json when serialized?

three type of Json Format

1. color   : "{\"type\":\"color\",\"data\":\"blue\"}"
2. message : "{\"type\":\"message\",\"action\":\"Change Color\"}"
3. history : "{\"type\":\"history\",\"data\":[{\"time\":1384825833181,\"text\":\"this is test\",\"author\":\"Tom\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"time\":1384842730192,\"text\":\"WinForm Send\",\"author\":\"WinForm Say Hello!\",\"color\":\"orange\"},{\"time\":1384842808185,\"text\":\"WinForm Send Again!!!\",\"author\":\"WinForm Say Hello!\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"time\":1384843229766,\"text\":\"I am fine\",\"author\":\"who are you\",\"color\":\"red\"}]}"

All of the 3 Json formats can create 3 different Class with JsonProperty to map them.
I can verify string with the first few characters.
Are there any other solutions?

I found the following solution could help.

1. Use JsonCreationConverter . [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)
2. Use JavaScriptSerializer with dynamic type
   [Parse json string using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244149/parse-json-string-using-json-net)

   ```
   var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(e.Message.ToString());
   ```
3. Use JObject.Parse with dynamic type
   [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: I found JsonCreationConverter could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialized data is as string so, its just a string. As you have also told that you want to identify JSON format. So, better is first convert to JSON & then identify the JSON data type and based on the type call the process or method to process that data.

Comment: according to your suggestion. I found second solution to use JavaScriptSerializer with dynamic type. thanks.